# How to get cart in sales_order_create in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

I have a custom module admin page from there I want to add product in cart and redirect to `admin/sales_order_create/` page to place order for selected product.

For this I have created a controller action as below :

```
$customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id');
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$form_key = Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getFormKey();
$params = array('form_key' => $form_key,'qty'   =>1,);

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
$cart->save();
/* here I want to set quote in session so that it visible on redirected page */
$this->_redirect('*/sales_order_create', array('customer_id' => $customer_id,'quote_id'=>$cart->getQuote()->getId()));
```

This controller action redirect to `admin/sales_order_create` page with customer selected but I want to also set quote in session so that it's product would be seleced on new order page.

How do I do that?